# Youtube api and Samsung SmartTV App resolutions

Tags: youtube, samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

im working on Smart TV app for Samsung which should use youtube api to play videos. Embedded videos will work only when app resolution and yt player size are 960x540 or below,
if I set higher  resolution (1280x720 or 1920x1080) player stucks, behaves really slow, and videos will buffer infinitely.

Has anyone succeeded in embedding yt videos with higher resolution player?
Thx in advance.

Comment: what is your app resolution? check at widget.info file

Comment: As i said above. I tried with all three resolutions. (i know how to set them).
Anyway, i found a workaround solution: increase player after video starts playing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx all for answering,
in the end I used different approach which showed like best solution.

I used 720p resolution, and youtube cue video functionality.
Basically i cued video, and on "videoCued" event i called "playVideo" method.

This allowed player to get ready and initialize before playing video.

Comment: Is this the App installed on Samsung TVs? Is there a way for the user to specify the desired download resolution? Sometimes, when pay-by-the-megabyte data plans are used, it might be nice to give up a great picture and save $$$. It would be great if there were such a setting.

Answer (score 0):

Video player work in FullHD resolution in fullscreen regardless of widget resolution.

If you have troubles with buffering, check your connection speed. Try play file from local network to check that selected resolution and codecs hadled well by TV.

Answer (score 0):

recently i found this case. The youtube apps working great on 720p resolution if the video length is below 10min, but longer than that for example 30min the player will stuck just like as you said.

When changing the app resolution to 540p the youtube player working great again for all videos. I suppose the youtube is using progressive download on their player and Smart TV storage itself is not enough to prepare the long video storage space with 720p resolution rendering.

The conclusion is when using flash player/youtube in apps the best at using 540p app resolution.